# Stretch image background of a linear layout which serves as cell in gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have this cell item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/titleText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#AA000000" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

and this GridView:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

I want to set linear layout's background image but, according to image size, I get different heigths for cells (I use different images) which is not very good looking...how can I stretch the background to a fixed heigth?
Unfortunately gridview seems not have a columnHeigth attribute...

Comment: Define height and width of the linear layout in terms of 'dp'and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to [chet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087300/chet) 's advice: I set heigth and width of linear layout.